# How to adjust div height Automatically depending on another resizable div

Tags: html, angular, resize

I'm using angular2-draggable module to resize div vertically. You can see this demo: https://xieziyu.github.io/angular2-draggable/#/resizable/default, in the Resizable Demo area.
What I wanted is, when resize the top div，the below div height decrease or increase, instead of move down. That is, this whole page height never change, just two div heights mutual adjustment. Is there anyone knowing how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with some simple css. Create a parent container that covers the full page, apply a flex-box style with column direction, and make the bottom element automatically resize to fit available space. e.g.

```
<div class="container" style="height:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column">
    <div ngResizable>
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-div style="flex:1">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems its not working for me. When I resize the resizable div, the bottom div is still moving down or up.